# Incorrect behavior node.getData() java7 (64bit) vs java6 (32bit)

Tags: java, dom

I recently transitioned a project from JDK 1.6 (32-bit) to JDK 1.7 (64-bit).  An interesting issue appeared with org.w3c.dom.Node.  The following code works correctly with JDK1.6 but node.getData() only returns a subset of the data, sometimes, for JDK1.7 (64-bit). The data is a base-64 encoded.  Any ideas why this would be the case?

```
...
import org.w3c.dom.Text;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
...
public byte[] getToken() {

   Text node = getFirstToken();

   if (node == null) {
       return null;
   }

   // This fails for JDK 1.7 64-bit sometimes and does
   // not return all the data for the element.
   // works fine for JDK 1.6 32-bit
   String nodeData = node.getData();

   ....

   return Base64.decode(nodeData);


}
```

Comment: Maybe relevant, the javadoc for `getData()` states _DOMException - DOMSTRING_SIZE_ERR: Raised when it would return more characters than fit in a DOMString variable on the implementation platform._

Comment: I think you omit to much code. I don't really believe, that there is an error in the JVM libs. I think you may have a multithread bug (if multithreaded). Especially in copying byte[] can multithread bugs easilly created.